# Indent all lines after a certain character until another character

Tags: java, parsing, indentation

For an assignment we are creating a java program that accepts a java file, fixes messy code and outputs to a new file.

We are to assume there is only one bracket `{` `}` per line and that each bracket occurs at the end of the line. If/else statements also use brackets.

I am currently having trouble finding a way to indent every line after an opening bracket until next closing bracket, then decreasing indent after closing bracket until the next opening bracket. We are also required to use the methods below:

Updated code a bit:

```
public static void processJavaFile() {
        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `line = line.replaceAll ("^", "    ");`

Comment: I think you need to provide sample of what you need, the input and the output so that we know what you wanna do.

Comment: It’s unclear whether your problem is with calculating the correct indentation, with indenting the line correctly or something else. Please show us your code and specify the observed behaviour so we know. It’s our only chance to give you useful guidance.

Comment: The two method skeletons sound like a good way to a good design (which is more than can be said about many other homework assignment requirements).

Comment: I suggest that in `processJavaFile()` you look at the last character of the line. If it is `{`, you increase the indent level *after* having printed the line. If it is `}`, you decrease it *before*  printing the line.

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm should get you started. I left a few glitches that you'll have to fix. 
(For example it doesn't indent your { brackets } as currently written, and it adds an extra newline for every semicolon)

The indentation is handled by a 'depth' counter which keeps track of how many 'tabs' to add.

Consider using a conditional for loop instead of a foreach if you want more control over each iteration. (I wrote this quick n' dirty just to give you an idea of how it might be done)

```
public String parse(String input) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    int depth = 0;
    boolean isNewLine = false;
    boolean wasSpaced = false;
    boolean isQuotes = false;
    String tab = "     ";
    for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        switch (c) {
        case '{':
            output.append(c + "\n");
            depth++;
            isNewLine = true;
            break;
        case '}':
            output.append("\n" + c);
            depth--;
            isNewLine = true;
            break;
        case '\n':
            isNewLine = true;
            break;
        case ';':
            output.append(c);
            isNewLine = true;
            break;
        case '\'':
        case '"':
            if (!isQuotes) {
                isQuotes = true;
            } else {
                isQuotes = false;
            }
            output.append(c);
            break;
        default:
            if (c == ' ') {
                if (!isQuotes) {
                    if (!wasSpaced) {
                        wasSpaced = true;
                        output.append(c);
                    }
                } else {
                    output.append(c);
                }
            } else {
                wasSpaced = false;
                output.append(c);
            }
            break;
        }
        if (isNewLine) {
            output.append('\n');
            for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
                output.append(tab);
            }
            isNewLine = false;
        }
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```